# Как использовать qsshfs?

Tags: linux, ssh, kde, manjaro, sshfs

Не очень понятно как использовать данную утилиту. Подключаюсь к удаленному серверу с ключами и парольной фразой. Через консоль всё успешно

```
sshfs user@1.1.1.1:/ /home/mnt/server
```

Сделал конфигурационный файл:

```
cat ~/.ssh/config 
Host server
  HostName 1.1.1.1
  Port 22
  User user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Но GUI все время меня посылает. Гугл не помог мне с этим вопросом (или я не знал как искать).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
uname -a
Linux home-lx 5.7.0-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon May 4 04:32:32 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Собственно сам пакет https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/qsshfs/

Answer (score 0):

Установите программу askpass

```
pacman -S ksshaskpass
```

или одну из этих

```
ksshaskpass - для kde/plasma
openssh-askpass - универсальная
lxqt-openssh-askpass - для lxqt
x11-ssh-askpass - простенькая
seahorse - для гномов
```

Возможно понадобится перелогиниться.

P.S. Я пользуюсь же просто в файловом менеджере набираю `sftp://user@1.1.1.1/` и файловая система ssh подключается.